# How to set the OS to main start instead of the recovery?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, twrp, fastboot, motorola-moto-e

I have a Moto E 1st Gen and it got into a loop, so I flashed it, installed TWRP and upgraded to Android 5.1, everything went fine (I guess) but when I power on the device, it starts on the recovery (TWRP) not Android, no matter how many times I reboot. On the other hand I do can access android but by entering to fastboot mode and then selecting normal startup, if I do that, Android starts just fine, but, every time I power off the phone and start it again like that, Android optimizes all apps (as if it were the first time Android is running). My question is, how can I set Android to boot when I power on the phone instead of TWRP? thanks in advance

Comment: Flash stock firmware using RSD lite. Download the firmware at firmware.center/firmware